# MySQL Error: Unknown column 'dob' in 'field list' - Possible Reasons

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have amended by mysql database to add a new column to an existing table and also added a new table.

When I run my php code which inserts some data to this table, it comes up with the error message :

MySQL Error: Unknown column 'dob' in 'field list'

I know that this column is spelt correctly and definately in the table.  When I amend my code so it doesnt insert in to that column it works as expected.

What i'm asking is there any other reason why it would not recognise a new column I have added to the table.  When I check via phpmyadmin, the column looks fine.

This is really strange and not a spelling mistake.  I have also added a new table to the database, which I can view via phpmyadmin, but when trying to insert via php mysql command, it says table does not exist.

Comment: If possible, show us the table schema and the query

Comment: what @JohnConde said, also make sure to add php code that calls that query.

Comment: Ensure the change in the database table is committed, so that all extra queries may see it.  Exit the PHPMyAdmin and then reconnect should ensure it is added.  Possibly you have a format error (quotes used/missing) in your query.  Otherwise, as the previous comments have mentioned, show the table definition and code.

Comment: maybe, you should not give the right name of dob,..your giving input are like different form database;